# html scoped IDs workaround

Tags: html, xml

I need to find a way to implement the concept of "scoped IDs" in HTML/XML.

I know that the `id` attribute of an element must hold a unique value for the entire document, but I'm wondering if there's a workaround ('hack', 'cheat', whatever) that I can do to create *scoped* IDs. That is, for any particular sectioning/containing element, IDs would be unique, but outside of the container, those IDs would be hidden and couldn't be referenced. With nested sections, inner sections will still be able to access their parent section's element's IDs but not the other way around.

I thought about using `<iframe>`s, but those are just icky.

Maybe there's a solution using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Use a prefix, or just deal with it and use classes instead.

Comment: No, no such hack, cheat exists.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what why you can't use classes, but you could use JavaScript to turn IDs into classes.

Comment: I don't want to use classes because I have mathematical variables with IDs, so that in case the variable representation changes (e.g. from `x` to `y`), all references to that variable will still work (e.g. `x+3` becomes `y+3`). Using global IDs isn't a problem, but once I'm out of a particular section, I won't use that specific variable anymore, so I'd like to "throw out" the ID so it can be used in another section.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

This is exactly what classes are for though.  Give unique IDs to each "section" or container element and then use classes for the common descendant elements you wanted to use recurring IDs for, then target them with `#unique-container .common-element` selectors.

I find it hard to imagine a situation in which you would want to do what you described anyway.  You are basically just asking if you can use IDs as classes, but that's why classes exist in the first place.

I suppose you could make some kind of psuedo-scoped-ID by adding custom HTML5 attributes to the elements and processing them / doing whatever you want to do with them in Javascript but again without any context as to why you want to do this it's hard to really recommend anything here.

Comment: @keyuratcodebins.com glad you didn't take offense, I was just worried someone who is relatively inexperienced might see it and not understand that it was invalid markup :)